# Can you plant a strawberry from fruit?

Tags: strawberries

I have an alpine strawberry plant which produces fruit (and no runners).

How can I make a second plant from this one?

Can I remove the seeds from a fruit and plant them?

Comment: I'm growing Alexandria and Yellow Wonder from seed, this year; I have plants that finally aren't extremely tiny. After I get fruit, I plan to grow the seeds again (every generation for several generations). So, I can let you know my experience when I get some. But, yes, you can grow the seeds. I'm not sure how they prepare and preserve them, but Baker Creek offers the seeds, which are quite viable, and they would know.

Comment: For strawberries, varietals, resistance to disease, everbearing or June bearing are critical to understand.  In my experience, two years for strawberry plants is maximum.  There are big reasons for this; disease, disease and disease.  My strawberries because I am the boss are 4 years old, the production has gone way down.  I plant new strawberries in other beds not having known a strawberry or disease.

Comment: Hard to chuck vigorous plants because you are taught this is the only way to continue to have strawberries.  Rotation, new plants, from NEW seed not the rag tag seed one gets without knowing or specializing in making seed.  To grow our own or extract seeds from a completely iffy production method well, one needs more humility.  You have absolutely no idea what your seed will produce.  None.  And two years, throw away the plants is a normal practice with those who make money from growing strawberries.

Comment: Mine are still 4 years and little fruit but I do know I am pushing things and have new crops of strawberries planted elsewhere.

Answer (score 5):

If by alpine strawberry you mean Fragaria vesca, then it's possible to grow them from seed. I have grown them from store-bought seeds and they germinated after a few months because I haven't watered them constantly. Each plant made 3-4 fruits the next year. The plants were not as well developed like normal ones because I have kept them indoors during the winter.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to grow from your own strawberry fruit seeds rather than buying seeds, there's some advice here, but its a UK site, so when it talks about 'compost' it means potting soil, and if you're in USA, the recommended 'compost', John Innes, is unfortunately not available where you are. The nearest equivalent I think you would call 'starter soil' for pots or trays, and we'd call it seed and cutting potting compost. According to this, you could just plant a mature, dried off fruit from your own plants - otherwise it tells you how to process the fruits to collect the seeds
http://gardenofeaden.blogspot.co.uk/2009/03/how-to-collect-and-prepare-strawberry.html